# Help clarifying confusion about many-particle states on Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator

Suppose I have many particles distributed in two states $a$ and $b$, if a fraction of particles in the $a$ is denoted by $n_a$, and the fraction of particles in the $b$ state denoted by $n_b$, some of the books I've seen suggest that the density matrix for this ensemble could be written as

$$n_a|a\rangle\langle{a}| + n_b|b\rangle\langle{b}|.$$

> As in Reichi's book (A Modern Course in Statistical Physics) on the chapter about the density state matrix (Exercise 6.6)

However, if I think of the possible combinations, I could write a state $|\psi\rangle$ whose basis vectors represent every possible combination of states that these particles could assume. So, for example, if I had only 3 particles, the $|\psi\rangle$ state could be

$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\left(|a\rangle|a\rangle|a\rangle +  |a\rangle|a\rangle|b\rangle + |a\rangle|b\rangle|a\rangle + |a\rangle|b\rangle|b\rangle ... + |b\rangle|b\rangle|b\rangle\right),$$

> As in Jack D. Hidary book (Quantum Computing: An Applied Approach)

Meaning that the density matrix would be a $2^n\times2^n$ operator instead of a two by two.

Which one of these is the correct one? Are these representations interchangeable?

Comment: References... ?

Comment: Your second example describes only a single entangled state of the system and not a distribution of multiple states (=density operator). The corresponding density operator to the second example is $| \psi \rangle \langle \psi|$ (a pure state).

Comment: @jd27, is there a hypothetical Physical process that could get the probability density matrix of a pure state to a mixed state and vice-versa? I'm confused about this because there's $N$ particles on both cases, and it seems that one should be an edge case of the other, right? How can I tell which one to use if I don't know whether the particles are entangled or not?

Comment: Mixed states have the property $\mathrm{tr}\{\rho^2\}<1$, whereas pure states have $\mathrm{tr}\{\rho^2\}=1$. This has nothing to do with the basis (single-particle or many-particle), nor with entanglement.

Answer (score 1):

The first expression is representing the density matrix of a mixed state of particles where each individual particle is not in a superposition of the states $|{a}\rangle$ and $|{b}\rangle$. When there is no superposition, the off-diagonal coherence terms are zero.

The second expression you gave is a pure state which would have the off-diagonal terms that you suggest. Entanglement is not necessary for the density matrix to have off-diagonal terms, only superposition is. In fact, the state you provided as an example is not entangled as you can write it as a product of three individual particle states, but it would still have all non-zero terms in its corresponding density matrix.

The wording that suggests that the "correct" choice in this case is the first expression is the "many particles distributed in two states" part. This indicates that each individual particle is in either state a or state b and not in a superposition of the two. In this case, the density matrix for the ensemble will be a mixed state where each term on the diagonal corresponds to the population fraction of that state in the ensemble.